# Find All Possible Duplicate Records In Single Table Single Column (T-Sql)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table and having id and name columns. 
I want to find all possible duplicate records from name column.

Condition:

1. No input will be provided, it's like self-search.
2. it has to search and display a list of possible duplicate records set
3. Search must be like free text search

One possible set I have as below for example. It looks like the hair is possible common duplication so it becomes set.I need duplicates looking multiple sets.

- Big Sexy Hair

  EVE Hair

  girly

  HAIR CORP

  hair dryer

  Hair Flairs

  Haircare

  Hairobics

  Iris

  It's a 10 Haircare

Can anyone help with or having any query or algorithm which can fulfill this requirement?

Comment: can you provide some sample input data and the query you have tried so far.

Comment: Can't get it? You are looking for exact text match or for close text meaning?

Comment: You can take any example data table like a product, category, brand. I have not tried anything so far. I can't provide my data to you

Comment: I am looking for close text meaning

Comment: this can be an application for machine learning in connection with a large dictionary (in multiple languages?). considering "CHAIR" and "HAIR" and "CROSSHAIR"... what if "GIRLY" was "CURLY", would it then also be hair-related? this is fuzzy, and cannot be reduced to a mere "contains x" query. the standard tsql functions like `LIKE` and `SOUNDEX` are not sufficient. for a start, tokenize it, discard fill words and non-words, and track number of occurrence of each token, and output those lines which end up with a token occurrence count >= 2.